# adding the sum of a group SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

new to sql and having trouble finding a query example.

So, I have a table:

```
bought ( customer_name, month, year, quantity, product_name )
```

I want to find the product that sold the most in a particular month EX. April 2014

lets say:

```
| Jan | April | 2014 | 7 | Watches |
| Ron | April | 2014 | 4 |  Rings  |
| Jan | April | 2014 | 4 |  Rings  |
```

right now I have:

```
SELECT product_name
FROM bought
WHERE month_bought = 'April' AND year_bought = 2014 AND 
           quantity_buy >= all (SELECT quantity_buy
                                FROM bought 
                                WHERE month_bought = 'April' AND year_bought = 2014
                               );
```

I am unsure if/where to use GROUP BY for the product_name.

Comment: Consider storing years and months as a single entity

Comment: Subclass of [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need aggregation because multiple customers could purchase the same product.  That in turn suggests `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`:

```
SELECT product_name
FROM bought b
WHERE month_bought = 'April' AND year_bought = 2014 
GROUP BY product_name
HAVING SUM(quantity_buy) >= all (SELECT SUM(b2.quantity_buy)
                                 FROM bought b2
                                 WHERE b2.month_bought = b.month_bought AND 
                                       b2.year_bought = b.year_bought
                                 GROUP BY product_name
                               );
```

There are other ways to express this query.  This seems closest to what you are trying to write.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error for the group by on the 4th line.

Answer (score 0):

Without further testing it should be something along these lines:

```
SELECT product_name

FROM bought

WHERE month_bought = 'April' AND year_bought = 2014 AND 

       sum(quantity_buy) = (SELECT max(sum(quantity_buy)) FROM bought 

       WHERE month_bought = 'April' AND year_bought = 2014 group by  product_name)
group by product_name;
```

This will return multiple products IF they were sold in same quantities.